# Cumulative distribution function and right continuity

Tags: calculus, probability

Could you provide an example that will help to understand why we need this requirement:

> CDF should be right continuous.

What if CDF would be left continuous? What kind of problems would we meet with left continuous CDF?

Answer (score 2):

That the CDF has to be right continuous follows from the continuity from above of the probability measure. For any measure whatsoever, if we have a decreasing sequence of sets $A_n$ decresing to $A$, that is $A_n\supset A_{n+1},\forall n$ and $A=\bigcap_{i=1}^{\infty}A_i$, then $\mu(A_n)\downarrow\mu(A)$. Now if $x_n\downarrow x$, then $\{X\leq x_n\}\downarrow\{X\leq x\}$, thus $F(x_n)\downarrow F(x)$.

The CDF need not be left continuous. Because in general a measure is not continuous from below. For example when $X$ is a discrete random variable, suppose its distribution assigns positive mass to the point $x_0$, then $F(x_0)-F(x_0-)=P(X=x_0)>0$, hence the CDF of a discrete random variable is left discontinuous at points where a positive probabilitymass is assigned.

Comment: I should have mentioned that math isn't my major. So, I didn't get what you've tried to show. Suppose, we have $f(x)=0$ for $x\in [0,1]$ and $f(x)=1$ for $x \in (1,2]$. Obviously, this is not right continuous function. But why this function cannot represent some CDF?

Comment: Because $F(x)$ is nothing but the probability of the event $\{X\leq x\}$. See the axioms of probability theory first. The book by Feller of probability is a very good reference. http://www.amazon.com/Introduction-Probability-Theory-Applications-Edition/dp/0471257087