# Properties of inverse distribution function - continuity

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I have some questions about inverse distribution functions. Let $F : \mathbb R \to [0,1]$ be a distribution function and define $F^{-1} : [0,1] \to \overline{\mathbb R}$ by $F^{-1}(y) := \inf\{x \in \mathbb R; F(x) \ge y\}$ with the convention that $\inf \emptyset := +\infty$. Futhermore, define $F^{-1+} : [0, 1] \to \overline{\mathbb R}$ by $F^{-1+}(y) := \sup\{x \in \mathbb R; F(x) \le y\}$, where $\sup \emptyset := -\infty$.

The function $F^{-1}$ is the usual quantile function. I managed to prove the following properties:

1. $F^{-1}$ and $F^{-1+}$ are non-decreasing.
2. If $F^{-1} \in (-\infty, \infty)$, $F^{-1}$ is left-continuous at $y$ and admit a limit from the right at $y$.
3. For $y \in \mathbb R$, set $A_y := \{x \in \mathbb R; F(x) = y\}$. Then, $(F^{-1}(y-), F^{-1}(y+)) \subseteq A_y$.
4. Suppose that $F$ is strictly increasing. Then, $F^{-1}$ is continuous.

It would be nice, if I could prove the properties 2 and 4 also for $F^{-1+}$. Do they hold also for $F^{-1+}$? I needed property 3 to prove 4.

Comment: Sorry, this was my error, I meant just the distribution function of a some random variable $L$. But see my edit in the question, now it should be clear.

Comment: For 2. you want to prove $F^{-1+}$ are right continuous?

Comment: Yes, if that is a true statement, I do not know if $F^{-1+}$ is left- or right-continuous.

Comment: I still do not understand quite understand the proof of (4).

Answer (score 3):

The function $F^{-1+}$ is continuous from the right. To see this let
$y_{0}$ be such that $x_{0}:=F^{-1+}(y_{0})\in\mathbb{R}$ and consider a
sequence $y_{n}\searrow y_{0}$. Set $F^{-1+}(y_{n}):=x_{n}$. Since $F^{-1+}$
is non-decreasing, $F^{-1+}(y_{0})\leq F^{-1+}(y_{n+1})\leq F^{-1+}(y_{n})$
and so $x_{0}\leq x_{n+1}\leq x_{n}$. It follows that $x_{n}\searrow x$ with
$x_{0}\leq x$.

Since $x_{n}=F^{-1+}(y_{n})=\sup\{x:\,F(x)\leq y_{n}\}$ for every
$\varepsilon>0$ we have $F(x_{n}-\varepsilon)\leq y_{n}<F(x_{n}+\varepsilon)$.
If by contradiction $x_{0}<x$, then taking $\varepsilon:=\frac{x-x_{0}}{2}$ we
have that $x_{n}-\varepsilon>x_{0}+\varepsilon$ and so by monotonicity
$y_{n}\geq F(x_{n}-\varepsilon)\geq F(x_{0}+\varepsilon)>y_{0}$. Letting
$n\rightarrow\infty$ and using the fact that $y_{n}\searrow y_{0}$ we get a
contradiction. This shows that $x_{n}\searrow x_{0}$, that is, that $F^{-1+}$
is continuous from the right.

That $F^{-1+}$ admits a limit from the left follows from the fact that
$F^{-1+}$ is non-decreasing. So (2) holds with right continuous in place of left.

Answer (score 0):

So $F_X(x)=P(X\le x)$

I will prove (4.) - "Suppose that $F$ is strictly increasing. Then, $F^{−1+}$ is continuous"

Opposite would be: there is $y_o$ and there is $m>0$ such that $\forall\delta>0,\exists y,|y-y_0|<\delta \land |F^{−1+}(y)-F^{−1+}(y_0)|>m$

Let $x_0=F^{−1+}(y_0)$ since **$F$ is right continuous** then $F(x_0)\ge y_0$

So we have 
$$F(x_0-m)<y_1<F(x_0-m/2)\le y_0\le F(x_0)<y_2<F(x_0+m/2)$$
where $y_1$ and $y_2$ are arbitrary numbers that satisfy the inequatity.

Also analogically 
$$x_0-m\le F^{−1+}(y_1)\le x_0\le F^{−1+}(y_2)\le x_0+m/2$$
and  since $F^{−1+}$ is increasing $|F^{−1+}(y)-x_0|<m$ for all {$y|y_1<y<y_2$}

EDIT - further explanation of some statements

Why is $F(x_0) \ge y_0$?

If it was not, meaning $F(x_0) < y_0$, then from definition of $F^{-1+}$ we have $F(x)>y_0$ for all $x>x_0$, in other words $P(x_0<X\le x)>y_0-F(x_0)$ for all $x>x_0$ which is impossible because $F$ has to be right continuous, see [Cumulative distribution function and right continuity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/492774/cumulative-distribution-function-and-right-continuity)

Comment: Could you explain a little bit further please? I do not really see why $F(x_0) \ge y_0$, why we can choose $m$ such that $m < y_0$ and $m < 1 - y_0$ and where is the contradiction exactly?

Comment: @numerion sorry for late answer, I haven't had time. The part  $m < y_0$ and $m < 1-y_0$ is absolutely unnecessary, even wrong, I'm not sure why I put it there, sorry. Contradiction is that there is interval around $y_0$ so that for all $y$ from that interval $|F^{−1+}(y)-F^{−1+}(y_0)|<m$

Answer (score -1):

$F$ is a distribution function, so at a point $x$ this function may only behave in a few different ways:

1. It may be continuous at $x$ and strictly increasing immediately after $x$. This means for all $x' > x$ we have $F(x') > F(x)$.
2. It may be continuous at $x$ and "flat" immediately after $x$. This means there is some $x' > x$ for which $F(x') = F(x)$.
3. It may have a jump discontinuity at $x$.

You can see each of these behaviors in the following picture:

[image]

You can also "see" (and then prove, as in the other answers) that the *only values of $y$ where $F^{-1+}(y)$ is discontinuous are the heights of the "flat parts" of $F$, in which case $F^{-1+}$ makes a right-continuous jump.* In light of this observation, your (2) is not true for $F^{-1+}$, which is right-continuous at its jumps, but your (4) is true, since a strictly increasing $F$ has no flat parts.